# displaying the required no. of JTextfields based on the value of a variable

Tags: java

I have read some records from a database into an array. I want to display the values from that array in different textfields. How do I refer to these textfields as I would not know the number of textfields to be enabled ? for eg I have textfields with names like srno, srno1, srno2, etc. Based on the no. of records I want to enable the required no. of textfields so that I can put the values of the array via setText(). I tried to define an array of JTextFields but that did not help.

The code prior to this problem is as below :

```
try{
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
     Connection con =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lalit","root","admin");
    Statement stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
    forCent();
    raceDate.getText();
    raceSrno.getText();
    ResultSet rs1 = stmt.executeQuery("Select  RM_CEN_CD ,RM_SR_NO,RM_DATE,"  
     +"RM_RACENO,RM_MINBET,RM_MINBETP from nr93rams"  
            +"where rm_cen_cd = trim('"+cenCode.getText()+"'),"
                    +"and rm_date = str_to_date('"+fd1+"','%Y-%m-%d')"
                 +"  and rm_raceno= "+mraceno);
    while (rs1.next())
    {
        minBet.setText(Integer.toString(rs1.getInt(4)));
        minBetpl.setText(Integer.toString(rs1.getInt(5)));
    }
        ResultSet rs2 = stmt.executeQuery("Select  count(*) from nr93radt"
        +"where rd_cen_cd = trim('"+cenCode.getText()+"'),and rd_date = "
            +"str_to_date('"+fd1+"','%Y-%m-%d') and rd_raceno= "+mraceno);

    int cntr = rs2.getInt(1);

        ResultSet rs3 = stmt.executeQuery("Select  RD_CEN_CD ,RD_SR_NO,RD_DATE,"
                     +"RD_RACENO,RD_HOR_CD,RD_JOCKEY,RD_WEIGHT from nr93ams"
                     +"where rm_cen_cd = trim('"+cenCode.getText()+"'), and rm_date = "
                     +"str_to_date('"+fd1+"','%Y-%m-%d') and rm_raceno= "+mraceno);
```

Based on the value of **cntr** I want to enable those no. of textfields.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have enough text fields to not be needing a scroll bar, you could, set the layout of the component to which you are adding the text fields to null and then, create and position the text fields as you wish.

You can create them on the fly and position them as needed. Every time you create a new text field, you add it to a List, and this should allow you to keep track of the elements you create.